# Saving State of TextView

Tags: textview, state, save

Im creating a app that in one activity the text view is constantly changing everytime the user enters a new piece of imformation. When the back button is pressed to return to the main menu, and the user re-enters the activity, it is recreated and starts from the beginning instead of where the user left off. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

That must be, because of reallocation of the TextView every time
it's shown again.
If you only create the instance *once*, it
will be saved.
Best, you save the TextView to an attribute of a class instance, or so.
Cheers,
Niklas

Comment: Okay thank you so much for helping me. So how can i create the textview only once when each onclick needs to have the textview initiated to change the text each time a onclick happens? An example would help. Thank so much man, i really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so ive figured it out.

The problem was that the back button finished the activity. What i did was override the onBackPress button and then started the main menu activity to return to the main menu. This allowed the state of the new activity to be saved and when the user clicks to return to the activity the data is still there and persistant. This will answer all the questions about trying to save on backButtonPressed. If you have any other questions just let me know and ill be glad to help.